# asp core 1.0.1 web api deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I m trying to deploy a WebApi in asp.net core 1.0.1
Can any one point me the way to do it on Windows 2012 server ?

If i create a new project on vs 2015 (with the webapi template with the default valuescontroller) and publish it as is it gives a 404 error page not found.

I instaled DotNetCore.1.0.1-WindowsHosting, created amnd app pool with no managed code and added a new website to it with the content from the publish folder (created by visual studio).

What am i doing wrong?

PS: if i run the app on visual studio it works (returns a json file)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add comment so I add my 2 cents here :

Suggestion to find the reason:

I try the following step (1) and it works. 
Maybe you can try (2) & (3) and then you may find out reason for your issue.

1. Use default web site (not a new web site) with DefaultAppPool (not a new pool)
2. If it works, use new web site with DefaultAppPool.
3. If it works, the issue may be the publishing-user with wrong credential on your new folder.

hope this help